# Orienting Shimano Cup and Cone square-taper bottom bracket spindle

Tags: bottom-bracket, crankset

I was servicing my Shimano adjustable bottom bracket and forgot which way the spindle was originally oriented.  Without measuring in detail, how do I correctly orient the spindle (so that the correct side is on the drive side)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One side of the spindle is a little longer than the other one. The longer side is the drive side. There may be spindles that have arms that are the same length, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Perfect, I was wondering about the markings.  As far as noticing that one is longer, it's pretty gosh darn close, but I'm not really used to using the eye with measurements this small.

Comment: Funny. I have a spindle in my hands where if I stand behind my bike and hold it out and read the letters, the longer side of the spindle is going out the non-drive side.

Comment: @JakeWilson I suppose you visited this post because you weren't sure how to install it... is this by chance not the case? Do you know which side was intended to be the drive side?

Comment: Correct. In this case, the longer side of the spindle is drive side. However, the way the stamped text is on the spindle, I would have to stand looking at the bike from the front in order to read the text.

Comment: @JakeWilson Post edited. Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score -1):

If there isn't an obvious longer end, install it such that any writing on the spindle reads normally, left-to-right. No matter what you'll just have to check the chainline and do it again if you mess up :)